# Tomcat crashes while access large database table

Tags: java, tomcat, crash

When my database request takes too long tomcat crashes / closes and I find this in my log. I am totally clueless right now :)

Any thoughts ?

```
SEVERE: The web application [/ir] is still processing a request that
has yet to finish. This is very likely to create a memory leak. You
can control the time allowed for requests to finish by using the
unloadDelay attribute of the standard Context implementation.
Mar 14, 2015 2:14:38 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader
clearReferencesThreads
SEVERE: The web application [/ir] appears to have started a thread
named [MySQL Statement Cancellation Timer] but has failed to stop it.
This is very likely to create a memory leak.
```

What should I be doing ?

Comment: I don't think it's crashing - it looks like you shut it down while it was still working on the request.

Comment: Hmmm. Well the tomcat command prompt automatically closes down.

Comment: Is there an OutOfMemeory error or something else in `catalina.out`?

Comment: Nothing in Catalina.out and no out of memory error